# Paired t-test null hypothesis correct wording

Tags: statistics

I am studying paired t-tests from the Handbook of Biological Sciences and I am not sure about the following claim: "The null hypothesis is that the mean difference between paired observations is zero. When the mean difference is zero, the means of the two groups must also be equal." Does that mean the following null hypotheses are equivalent or just that the first implies the second and how do you easily see that?

H0: the mean difference between the paired observations is 0.

H0: the difference between the paired population means is equal to 0.

Intuitively, those seem like quite different claims to make. When I looked into this, it seems that the first is used as the null hypothesis of paired t-tests frequently, but I also have found websites write the hypotheses in the format of the second null (such ashttps://libguides.library.kent.edu/SPSS/PairedSamplestTest). I was hoping somebody could shed some light on this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the null hypothesis $H_0$ is $\mathbb E[X_{1,j}-X_{2,j}]=0$ for the $j$th pair then this is equivalent to $\mathbb E[X_{1,j}]-\mathbb E[X_{2,j}]=0$, i.e. $\mathbb E[X_{1,j}]=\mathbb E[X_{2,j}]$.

That is a statement for the paired observations, but if  $\mathbb E[X_{1,j}]=\mathbb E[X_{2,j}]$ is true for each of the paired observations then $\mathbb E[X_1]=\mathbb E[X_2]$ across all the observations